# Neo4j Indexes and Constrains in a JS Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, graph-databases

I am using NodeJS to create a Neo4j application. I want to add constraints like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(userId)
```

But I do not know where to place this statement. If run twice, it throws an error of type:

```
Neo4jError: An equivalent index already exists, ...
```

Where should I place this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
CREATE INDEX userIdIndex IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:User) ON (n.userId)
```

Comment: That is great. Could you perhaps write me the equivalent for a CONSTRAINT? Thank you.

Comment: Here's the documentation link for constraints syntax. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/syntax/. It should solve your problem. Let me know if it doesn't